# Unable to create Hashset with CustomComparator

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I getting below error while creating Hashset/Hashmap with CustomComparator. 
I believe syntax is correct,but I am not sure why is it throwing error. Plz help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` and `HashSet` are NOT sorted collections, hence there's no constructor to take a `Comparator`. Instead you have to use `TreeSet` or `TreeMap` which contains an overloaded constructor to take in a `Comparator`. So the code should be corrected as this.

```
Map<Student, String> empMap = new TreeMap<>(new MyCustComparator());
Set<Student> set = new TreeSet<>(new MyCustComparator());
```